# Golangのテンプレートで改行が反映されない。

Tags: html, go

Golangのテンプレートを利用して、HTMLを出力しているのですが。

```
あああ
いいい
ううう
```

このような内容の文章を出力すると

```
あああ いいい ううう
```

と表示されてしまいます。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671713/golang-how-to-replace-n-with-br/12672021

上の方法を試しましたが

```
あああ <br>
いいい <br>
ううう <br>
```

となって`<br>`が表示されてしまいます。

http://m-shige1979.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/01/29/080000

こちらのサイトで紹介されている`safe`関数を用いた方法では`<br>`が評価され、改行されましたが、当然XSSの脆弱性があります。
どのようにすれば改行をHTMLに反映させることができるのでしょうか。

Comment: ここで「テンプレート」と言っているのは [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) のことでしょうか？

Comment: そうです。標準のhtml/templateです。

Comment: 関連: ["html/templates - Replacing newlines with <br>"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13779027/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サンプルとして、次のテキストを `p` タグの中に入れることを考えます。

```
const text = `あいう
かきく
さしす
`
```

### 方法1

エスケープした後、改行を `<br>` に変換するようにすれば良いです。 [(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/VAJJoNhHth)

```
const tpl = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>{{.}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("sample").Parse(tpl))
    safeText := template.HTMLEscapeString(text)
    replacedText := strings.Replace(safeText, "\n", "<br>", -1)
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, template.HTML(replacedText)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

### 方法2

あるいは1行ごとにスライスとして持っておけば [`range` アクション](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions)が使えるので、テキストではなくテンプレートの方に `<br>` を入れることができます。 [(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/JOEu1SD_6i)

```
const tpl = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>{{range .HeadLines}}{{ . }}<br>{{end}}{{if .LastLine}}{{ .LastLine }}{{end}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
`

func main() {
    // 末尾が改行されているかどうかで処理を分けなければいけない
    allLines := strings.Split(text, "\n")
    data := struct {
        HeadLines []string
        LastLine  string
    }{
        HeadLines: allLines[:len(allLines)-1],
        LastLine:  allLines[len(allLines)-1],
    }

    t, err := template.New("sample").Parse(tpl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。方法1でできました。